# Get svg image real size after resizing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a picture in a svg tag.
When I change the width (or the height) of the image, the height (or the width) also changes to keep the ratio.
But I am not able to get the new value of the height (or the width).

Here an example :
https://plnkr.co/edit/NrovrUKAv8KRGLPdjDpG?p=preview

We can see that although the width and the height are reduced, only the width value changes.
I tried to get the height using d3js, but value is still the same.

`d3.select("image").attr("height")`

Comment: can't You just recalculate both values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it appears to be height of the image is dropping but it actually is not its just the way it spread across with `changing width * 219` just to auto adjust into the frame. All more with a simple example what happens when try to make a `800*600 image a wallpaper in 1920*768 screen`. Check the below image to see how much screen has actually your image has occupied.

[image]

If you really want to resize your pic then you need to resize your height also accordingly and recalculate both the values:

```
 var height = parseInt(d3.select("image").attr("height"));
    d3.select("image").attr("height", height / 2);
```

Here is an [example](http://jsbin.com/yuqezijicu/edit?html,js,output).